# How to get the process ID of the program that called a system function

Tags: c, linux-kernel, hook, ftrace

I am writing a small kernel driver that has the job to act as a honeypot and monitor actions taken on a specific file on the system. To start things off, [I used the code in this repository](https://github.com/ilammy/ftrace-hook/blob/master/ftrace_hook.c), which I then slightly modified for simplicity reasons so that it works only for one system call: `sys_open`.

Now I need to gather information for the process and the user that run that system call to open this file, but I could not find any way to do it. I thought that I could use the file descriptor to identify which process has it, but after a discussion with my university professor, he told me that file descriptors are NOT unique system-wide, but only process-wide.

To conclude, is there a way that could give me the PID of the process that implicitly called `sys_open`?

Comment: Maybe you can find out how the getpid system call works. getpid must be able to know the process ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running in kernel code, information about the currently running process is stored in the `current` global variable (it's actually a platform specific macro rather than a global variable, to be precise), which is a [`struct task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L629). If you are inside a syscall handler (or a hook to one), then `current` will be the process which started the syscall, and you can just check `current->pid` to get its PID.

To get the current process' UID, GID, EUID, EGID (and so on) you can use the set of macros defined in [`linux/cred.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/cred.h#L379). From the [relative kernel documentation page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/security/credentials.html?highlight=current_uid#accessing-task-credentials):

> There are convenience wrappers for retrieving specific aspects of a task’s credentials (the value is simply returned in each case):
>
> ```
> uid_t current_uid(void)     // Current's real UID
> gid_t current_gid(void)     // Current's real GID
> uid_t current_euid(void)    // Current's effective UID
> gid_t current_egid(void)    // Current's effective GID
> /* ... */
> ```